# Reading from /dev/urandom does not return enough bytes

Tags: c, unix, random, cryptography, posix

Trying to write a one-time pad implementation, most of the time I end up with key sizes shorter than the plaintext.

Already tried multiple APIs such as `read()` and `fread()` from `/dev/(u)random`, linux `getrandom()` and even openssl `RAND_bytes()`. Whenever I check the length returned from those functions, it gives me the right amount of bytes, but the string itself (and therefore the keyfile) are somehow shorter.

Also tried with different datatypes, such as `int`, `uint8_t` and `wchar_t`, and loops, but to no avail.

```
char *genkey(const size_t length)
{
    char *key;

    key = calloc(length, sizeof *key);
    if (!key) ERROR("could not allocate memory\n");

    getrandom(key, (length * sizeof *key), 0);

    return key;
}
```

Comment: At least one of the random bytes is 0 — so if you measure it as a string, it will typically be shorter as a string than the length you requested.  You are getting a byte array, not a string.

Comment: Yes, that was precisely the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of the random bytes is 0 — so if you measure it as a string, it will typically be shorter as a string than the length you requested.

You are getting a byte array, not a string, from your random number generators.